# Function triggers immediately when I start to type a value to input area

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to calculate total duration from the entered values. But when I start to type, it triggers the calculateTotal function. And gives me this error:

`ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'null: 273'. Current value: 'null: 294'.`

Why this function triggers and changes the values randomly? Shouldn't it be triggered after clicking the button?

*app.component.html*

```
<div>
  <label>Duration</label>
  <input [(ngModel)]="durationModel.Duration" type="text" name="Duration" value="" #inputValue />
  <button (click)="addDuration()">Submit</button>
  <div [hidden]="durationList.length === 0">
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let duration of durationList">
        {{calculateDuration(duration)}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div>Total Duration : {{calculateTotal(21)}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*app.component.ts*

```
export class DurationModel {
  Duration: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  durationModel: DurationModel = new DurationModel();
  durationList = [];
  totalDuration = 0;

  addDuration() {
    this.durationList.push(this.durationModel.Duration);
    this.durationModel = new DurationModel();
  }

  calculateDuration(duration) {
    if (duration > 60) {
      const hours = Math.floor(duration / 60);
      const minutes = Math.floor(duration % 60);
      return `${hours} hours ${minutes} min.`;
    }
    return `${duration} min.`;
  }

  calculateTotal = (duration) => {
    console.log(duration);
    return this.totalDuration += duration;
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ak8p4t?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Go and use Custom pipe() in string interpolation of angular rather than directly calling function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because your html invokes the method `calculateTotal(...)` when the page loads. Make the following changes:

.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {

   calTotal;

   ...

  calculateTotal = (duration) => {
    console.log(duration);
    this.calTotal = this.totalDuration += duration;
  }


}
```

.html

```
<div>Total Duration : {{ calTotal }}</div>
```

Thereby, on click of the button the appropriate value is stored in `calTotal` and it can be retrieved in the template accordingly.

---

**EDIT**: 
Your approach to sum up the time entered by the user is way to complicated IMO. You can simplify it to:

.ts

```
export class AppComponent {

  durationList = [];
  totalDuration = 0;
  displayTotal: string;

  addDuration(time: number) {
    this.durationList.push(time);
    this.totalDuration = this.totalDuration + Number(time);
    this.displayTotal = this.calculateDuration(this.totalDuration);
  }

  calculateDuration(duration) {
    if (duration > 60) {
      const hours = Math.floor(duration / 60);
      const minutes = Math.floor(duration % 60);
      return `${hours} hours ${minutes} min.`;
    }
    return `${duration} min.`;
  }
}
```

.html

```
<div>
    <label>Duration</label>

    <input type="number" #inputValue />

    <button (click)="addDuration(inputValue.value)">Submit</button>

    <div [hidden]="durationList.length === 0">
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let duration of durationList">
                {{calculateDuration(duration)}}
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div>Total Duration : {{displayTotal}}</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ghphg)

Comment: This doesn't works. There is another problem which I don't have any clue. When you submit your first value you will see it loops the value again and again and when you try to type another duration value something interestingly happens and calls that function and concats the values even if you don't click submit button.

Comment: The error is gone - have a look [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ghphg).

Comment: Also, are you trying to sum up the time entered by the user? If yes, your approach is way to complicated.

Comment: I've assumed that is the case and have simplified your stackblitz. Have a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ghphg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). Let me know if it helped.